# ffmpeg: media convert audio from dolby to stereo

Tags: ffmpeg

I would convert a media file with this command

```
ffmpeg -i File1.avi -c:v h264 -c:a aac File1.mp4
```

But it convert only one channel audio of two, why?

[EDIT]
the orignal question was: *ffmpeg: media converted with only one audio channel*. I thout it was because I don't convert all track, but my problem was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must use `-ac 2` options, the media file has two track, and the first is 5.1 channel.

I can't hear the audio because my smart-tv doesn't play 5.1 track so I must downmix the track from 5.1 channel to stereo 2 channel

So I use ffmpeg with this options:

```
ffmpeg -i File1.avi -map 0:a:0 -c:v h264 -c:a aac -ac 2 File1.mp4
```

Comment: A smart-tv that is unable to play a 5.1 track should not be named "smart"... What happens if you directly play `File1.avi` on the tv ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i File1.avi -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v h264 -c:a aac -f mp4 File1.mp4
```

ffmpeg by default only picks one video, audio and subtitle track (if they are present) from among the sources. Express map assignments are required in order to include other streams. 0:a selects all audio streams.
And you need to explicitly specify output format in your case.

Comment: Ok, now I have `File1.mp4` with the two separate channel. but i think I must be merge all channel into one. Because I don't hear the second on my smart-tv

Comment: `-f mp4` is not needed here, ffmpeg can infer the format from the output file extension